# Exit Confirmation SweetAlert 2 - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, sweetalert

Boa Tarde Pessoal,

Conheci recentemente a biblioteca Sweet Alert. 
Estou tentando utilizá-la para sair de uma página, atualmente conto somente com uma function em TypeScript.

Gostaria de saber como transferir o sweet alert 2 para essa confirmação de saída.

```
  confirmarSair() {
const r = window.confirm("deseja sair?");
if (r) {
  window.sessionStorage.clear();
  window.location.href = `${environment.logoutUrl}?redirect_uri=${environment.noderedUrl}`;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
  }

Answer (score 2):

Navegando pela [documentação](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) é possível encontrar diversos exemplos.

O que você pretende realizar pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Deseja sair?',
    type: 'question',
    confirmButtonText: 'Sair',
    showCancelButton: true,
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
})
.then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
        window.sessionStorage.clear();
        window.location.href = `${environment.logoutUrl}?redirect_uri=${environment.noderedUrl}`;  
    }
})
```